# I have problems when I want to access the WSO2 admin

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

When I configure API Manager instead of localhost I use the IP address of the server, it does not show text or icons of the admin module, but on the local server it does show.

I modified the value of lcalhost in the depoyment file to the server's ip.

When I access the module https://192.168.1.5:9443/admin from an external client, it shows the following error in the browser debug.
[Access extern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUesb.png)
[Debug browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axcbj.png)

When I log in from a browser on the same server where the API manager is installed, I have no problems.
[Access in browser from same server of API Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlMLT.png)

Comment: which version of apim are you using ? If in 3.0 you have to change hostname/node ip in the deployment.toml file inside apim_home/repository/conf. Also what error is logged in carbon console ?

Comment: How about, I am using version 3.0, I already changed the deployment file I put the server's ip, in the carbon console there is no error so I have problems with a part of admin, the other services such as carbon, publisher, devportal income Normally without problems.